# ESP8266 NodeMCU node.dsleep option 4 with wifi connect command

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am using developer branch firmware and i am working on deepsleep mode. I use node.dsleep function with option 4. With this option after timer wake up there is no rf functionalty. My project is about temperature control  and i want connect wifi only when temperature data pass some limit. So I want use deepsleep mode option 4 with my control on wifi connection. Are there any command for connect wifi after wakeup deespsleep option 4.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=9963, according to the link you must do a `dsleep` with a different option to enable RF again.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 1 instead of 4 to dsleep().

Or use the same functions you'd usually use to initialize wifi and network.